# Can Nested if be applicable to filter dynamically changing range in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, dynamic, range, vlookup

Consider a data table in excel with 6 columns Min, Max, x, 17,18,19 and 3 user input. Output expected is an appropriate cell value to be returned from the table
when

1. my first userinput value lies within Min and Max(from table)
2. 2nd user input value matching any of the cell in column x
3. 3rd user input matching either 17/18 or 19

For Eg
Sample Data:

```
Min Max x    17 18 19
-------------------
1   7   0.5  1  2  3/n
8   10   1   2  5  7/n
8   10   2   8  4  9/n
8   10   3   0  7  4/n
11  12  0.5  3  2  1/n
```

If my user input is (8.4,2,18)
output expected is 4

[image: Sample data]

Comment: What have you tried and what problem did you encounter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`=INDEX(D2:F6,SUMPRODUCT((A2:A6<=A9)*(B2:B6>=A9)*(C2:C6=A10)*ROW(A2:A6))-ROW(A1),MATCH(A11,D1:F1,0))`

Where `SUMPRODUCT` calculates the row number meeting conditions for `min`, `max` and `x` minus the row number of the header row for correct indexing.
`Match` calculates the column for indexing.

[image]